# How to design layout like Android TV image given below

Tags: android, android-fragments, picasso

**I want to design the channel guide module using fragments and image loader(like Picasso)**.

How can I achieve it.? by using gridiew layout?

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Use Staggered grdiview like [this](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) or [this](https://github.com/smanikandan14/StaggeredGridView) or [this](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)